# Is there any way to find out the information about the owner of a repository in BitBucket using REST API?

Tags: rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to get the information about the owners of a list of repositories in BitBucket using REST API calls.

I'm able to access the commit details of the repositories and listing out the users but I'm focused on retrieving the owner information.

https://host:port/rest/api/1.0/projects/project_name/repos/repo_name/commits/?until=master

Comment: What version of Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Bitbucket version 6.0

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with the owner of a repository? Repositories' ownership is either a user (for personal repositories) or a project. To find a specific user as "owner" for a project, you could traverse through the permissions of the repository or project to check who is Admin or the like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have their UUID then https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo_slug} should include an "owner" object.